# How the speed of light remains stable inside a transparent material?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, speed-of-light

Velocity is initially reduced but then remains constant for as long as light is passing through a transparent medium like glass

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what kind of answers you expect. What do you mean be "remain stable"? If you are interested in a macroscopic description, why should it fluctuate? If you are interested in a microscopic description, this question has already been answered on SE.

Comment: Not to fluctuate,to reduce.Divide medium in layers.Question is totally different and not duplicated.